# onTouchEvent() only works in empty spaces?

Tags: java, android, onclick, touch-event

I am sure many other people would have faced this problem somewhere in the past.

My main.xml is divided into 9 `LinearLayouts` with weight 1 and `weightsum` is 9 of course.
1 layout is filled with empty space.

I have an `onTouchEvent()` function in my activity and it works perfectly fine.The problem is the touches are recognised only in the empty layout. Other layouts are filled with buttons and edittexts and textviews. But the touch event doesn't work there. I think the 'onClick' of the buttons is called before the `onTouchEvent()` can be called.

Is there any way I can make the touch work on the whole screen?

I haven't provided any code because its an general question which as per me doesn't require any code.
Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

because as [Activity doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) says :

```
   onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)  Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views under it.
 This is most useful to process touch events that happen outside of your window bounds, 
    where there is no view to receive it.
```

`onUserInteraction ()` method called when any touch event occur anywhere on the screen.